# DistributionS4 R Package

Tags: r, load

Been trying to load a data since ever. `load("Raw Inputs/PHL.RData")` only to encounter repeated errors below.

```
Loading required package: DistributionS4
Error in .requirePackage(package) : 
  unable to find required package ‘DistributionS4’
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
```

Please help :(

Update: DistributionS4 does not exist, hence installing the said package seems to be troubling.

Comment: ```install.packages('DistributionS4')``` - the error message is saying you don't have the package installed

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you, to use:

```
install.packages("DistributionS4", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Because it would also install the dependencies 'DistributionS4' depends on etc.

> dependencies: logical indicating whether to also install uninstalled
>             packages which these packages depend on/link
>             to/import/suggest (and so on recursively).  Not used if
>             ‘repos = NULL’.  Can also be a character vector, a subset of
>             ‘c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo", "Suggests",
>             "Enhances")’.

Comment: Hi, 

The package `DistributionS4` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: True, I searched also in github and found nothing. So it must be a private package or script file.